# Maximizing a strictly concave function over a compact convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (strictly) concave function, where

$S := \{y \in \mathbb{R}^m: y\geq 0,\, \sum_{i=1}^m y_i=1 \}$.

I want to show that there is a $y^*\in S$, which maximizes $f$. $S$ is a convex set and I found some results from convex optimization that strictly convex functions on convex sets have unique minimizers if local minima exist. Here, the set $S$ is also compact; how can we use this to prove the existence of a maximizing $y^*\in S$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apply the result yo have quoted to $-f$.

Comment: This result needs the existence of local minima of -$f$. How does this follow from the compactness of $S$?

Comment: @Max93: All convex functions are continuous (in fact, locally Lipschitz continuous), so you can appeal to the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) which says that continuous functions attain their maxima / minima over compact sets.

Comment: @VHarisop : Thank you! For the Extreme Value Theorem one needs that the function is continuous on the compact set, but doesn't it only follow from the convexity that the function is continuous on the interior? Why isn't this a problem?

Comment: @Max93: My apologies, I read the statement hastily and thought $f$ was defined everywhere.